# Can IgniteCache.lock be used as distributed lock

Tags: ignite

It looks that I can get a distributed lock through the API  `IgniteCache # public Lock lock(K key);`.

One thing I want to confirm is that when one process gets a lock from this object, but didn't release this lock before the process dies, will Ignite be sure that the lock that is held by the dead process be released， so that other processes that wait for the lock will get a chance to get the lock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ignite#reentrantLock* method have boolean flag *failoverSafe* which means exactly what you want. If node leave topology which already acquired a locks  then that the locks will be silently released.

Comment: Ignite Cache#lock(key) have the same failover semantic. But remember that it works only for transactional cache.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolay, I understood. Sound that `Ignite#reentrantLock` is NOT created against cache, so that there is no transactional cache problem with this API.

Comment: @Tom you are right. `Ignite#reentrantLock` creates separate synchronization primitive. `Ignite Cache.lock(key)` similar on pessimistic transaction with one key.